# How to use WhereNot in linq query over?

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I am finding it very hard to find examples on most of the queryover methods. For instance I have this

```
   .Where(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => tAlias.Course.Id), courseIds))
```

I want to "not" this

```
   .WhereNot(Restrictions.In(Projections.Property(() => tAlias.Course.Id), courseIds))
```

Yet you can't do this since you can use these Restrictions. So how how do you use WhereNot?

P.S

if anyone knows any other tutorial sites then  [this site](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx) let me know.

Comment: `.Where(!Restrictions`? i have no idea about this these frameworks. But thats what i would try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try two different ways to achieve this:

```
.Where(l => !tAlias.Course.Id.IsIn(courseIds))
```

Or

```
.Where(!Restrictions.On(() => tAlias.Course.Id).IsIn(courseIds));
```

Comment: I will try this but what is WhereNot for/

Comment: You can at least use it with simple expressions: .WhereNot(() => tAlias.Name == "C#")